# ASP.NET Web API Signalr not hitting OnConnected method

Tags: c#, jquery, signalr, azure-service-fabric, signalr.client

I have a Hub inside my ASP.NET Stateful project hosted on a local Service Fabric cluster, and I've overridden the ***OnConnected*** method. When putting a breakpoint on the ***OnConnected*** method, it's not entered, but at the same time, messages are properly broadcasted through the Hub.

Hub class:

```
public class NotificationHub : BaseHub
{
    private IFragStateManager _stateManager;
    private static IHubContext _context;

    public NotificationHub(IFragStateManager stateManager) : this(stateManager, _context)
    {
        _stateManager = stateManager;
        _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
    }

    private NotificationHub(IFragStateManager stateManager, IHubContext context) : base(stateManager, context)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Broadcasts payload to all clients
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="payload"></param>
    public void Broadcast(object payload)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Clients.All.broadcast(payload);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e.ToString());
        }            
    }

    //Investigate more why it's not hitting breakpoint while it actually connects and broadcasts messages
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

**_context.Clients.All.broadcast(payload);** works well. It delivers the payload successfully

Hub's base class:

```
    public abstract class BaseHub : Hub
    {
        protected IPrincipal User {
            get { return base.Context.User ?? _user; }
        }

        private ClaimsPrincipal _user;
        private Guid _userId;

        private IFragStateManager _stateManager;
        private IHubContext _context;

        public BaseHub(IFragStateManager stateManager, IHubContext context)
        {
            _stateManager = stateManager;
            _context = context;
        }        

        public override async Task OnConnected()
        {
            GetUserId();

            var map = await _stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<FragDictionary<Guid, string>>("UserConnectionMap");

            using (var tx = _stateManager.CreateTransaction())
            {
                var exisingValue = await map.TryGetValueAsync(tx, _userId);
                await map.SetAsync(tx, _userId, Context.ConnectionId);
                await tx.CommitAsync();
            }

            await base.OnConnected();
        }        

        public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            var map = await _stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<FragDictionary<Guid, string>>("UserConnectionMap");

            using (var tx = _stateManager.CreateTransaction())
            {
                await map.TryRemoveAsync(tx, _userId); 
                await tx.CommitAsync();
            }

            await base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }

        private void GetUserId()
        {

            if (Context.User == null)
                _user = (ClaimsPrincipal)(IPrincipal)Context.Request.Environment["server.User"];
            else
                _userId = new Guid(_user.FindFirst("AccountId").Value);
        }
    }
```

Hub client:

```
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8298/api/realtime/70c604f8-7996-4107-9ec3-28d08c869899/131810464642593740/4b98412e-8f09-4460-9c90-1d155cb8efca/signalr';

    var hub = $.connection.notificationHub;

    $.extend(hub.client, {
        broadcast: function (msg) {console.log(msg)}
    });

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        console.log('Connected');
    });
```

Client's scripts:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8298/api/realtime/70c604f8-7996-4107-9ec3-28d08c869899/131810464642593740/4b98412e-8f09-4460-9c90-1d155cb8efca/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

What has been checked already:

1. Downgraded SignalR. Went from 2.3 to 2.1. No results.
2. js client is already subscribing so probably no issues here.
3. When Hub is poked from the backend code, it broadcasts messages
   properly.